# How can I Export Image URLs to Excel

Tags: excel, image, api, export, podio

I am totally new to Podio Developer! I've managed to create an API key, but have no idea where to go from here. Basically I need to export data from an app to Excel. This works fine, but the images appear as Screenshot 2020-07-01 at 12.55.52.png" How do I get the whole url for the image to appear? I need to send this to our WIX web team.
I've seen various posts about code for this, but where do I even start inputting any code? Thanks!

Comment: Filter items and process the data as you wish,https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/filter-items-4496747

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in my post I am a complete beginner to this - where do I even put this code?